# Matplotlib Colorbar Renaming

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

So, I have a clustering with UMAP and I want to rename the colorbar on the right with the according labels.

```
My label mapping looks like this:
>>> {0: 'x', 1: 'y', 2: 'z', 3: 'xx', 4: 'yy', 5: 'zz', 6: 'xxxxx'}

sns.set(context="paper", style="white")
reducer = umap.UMAP()
embedding = reducer.fit_transform(user_df)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
cmap = 'Spectral'
c = user_df['label']

plt.scatter(embedding[:, 0], embedding[:, 1], cmap=cmap, c=c, s=30)
plt.colorbar(boundaries=np.arange(user_df['label'].nunique()+1)-0.5).set_ticks(np.arange(len(user_df['label'])))

plt.setp(ax, xticks=[], yticks=[])
plt.title('UMAP Clustering', y=1.01, size=15)
plt.savefig('UMAP Clustering.png', bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling `.set_ticks()`, get the return value of `plt.colorbar()` and then do the following:

```
cb = plt.colorbar(boundaries=np.arange(user_df['label'].nunique()+1)-0.5)
cb.set_ticks(np.arange(len(user_df['label'])))
cb.set_ticklabels(labels)
```

Please note that `labels` has to be the same length as the array given in `set_ticks()`.

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'Colorbar' object has no attribute 'set_labels'

Comment: My bad, it is `cb.set_ticklabels()`. Please see my edit.